# PHP/mySQL multi-dimensional array or object oriented approach?

Tags: php, mysql, oop, multidimensional-array

I have data that I want to pull from a mySQL database and I want to sort it in an organized way so I can pull it later.  I want to sort it in a matter where i have CompanyID $companyid: productID $productid: productName = $Product, industryName = $industry  etc

so essentially I want to have:

- CompanyID 1: ProductID 1: all the
  info about that specific product
- CompanyID 1: ProductID 2: all the
  info about that specific product
- CompanyID 1: ProductID 3: all the
  info about that specific product
- CompanyID 2: ProductID 1: all the
  info about that specific product
- CompanyID 2: ProductID 2: all the
  info about that specific product

etc etc

this is the while loop that pulls all the info, and where i will be storing it in either a multi-dimensional array or some object oriented class in PHP.  either way, i'm not too sure how to go about doing it.

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){ 
                $CompanyName=$row['CompanyName'];
                $companyid=$row['companyid'];
                $Product=$row['Product'];
                $productid=$row['productid'];
                $Industry=$row['Industry'];
                $Link=$row['Link'];
                $Keywords=$row['Keywords'];
                $region=$row['region'];}
```

EDIT:  I want to write a multi-dimensional array to capture all the data in an orderly manner.  how would I go about writing that or is that even the best solution?

EDIT:  right now i have this in the while loop:

```
 $companyIDArray[$companyid] = $productidArray[$productid] = $productInfoArray["CompanyName"]=$CompanyName;
```

and I am going to make one for each field.  Is that the best way to do it?

Comment: I know it's not what you're ultimately looking to accomplish, but that block of `$foo = $row['foo'];` statements can be done in one swoop with [`extract($row);`](http://php.net/extract).

Comment: you should add MYSQL_ASSOC to your mysql_fetch_array().  should look like `while ( $row = mysql_fetch_array( $result,MYSQL_ASSOC ) ) {`.  how long do you need to "store" your data construct?

Comment: just for the page but if I need it longer i'll put it in a $_SESSION variable

Comment: @b_dubb or use `mysql_fetch_assoc()` instead of `mysql_fetch_array()` for the same effect

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 $data = array();
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){ 

                $Industry=$row['Industry'];
                $Link=$row['Link'];
                $Keywords=$row['Keywords'];
                $region=$row['region'];}

 $data[$row['CompanyName'][$row['companyid']] = 
         array($row['Product'],$row['productid'], $Industry,$Link,$Keywords,$region );


}

print_r($data,true);
```

the above is untested code but it will give you an idea atleast how to do it.

Comment: how should I store all the product information? like the industry, link, keywords, region?

Comment: Add them also into the data array. under one company name

Answer (score 1):

You should be doing this in your SQL.  Use an **ORDER BY** clause like so:

```
SELECT
    companyid
    ,productid
    ,etc...
FROM
    products
ORDER BY
    companyid,
    productid
```

Comment: i want to store that information in a multi-dimensional array but i'm not sure how to go about doing it... something like $companyIDArray[$companyid] => $productidArray["$productid"] => $CompanyNameArray[$CompanyName]  etc